# Application has stopped working fault mode igdumdim.dll

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-media-player

I am working on a Winforms application which plays video after every feedback. The moment video is started, the application crashes. [image: Image 1![][1]] [image: Image2]

The same application is working perfectly on other systems. So the problem is only with this system.

- Playing video manually, it works.
- Changing disk, that also didn't helped.

It only gives the error the moment the video is started. I tried [this](https://communities.intel.com/message/143745) but is didn't help.

Comment: It looks like you are running inside a VM? Have you tried attaching a remote debugging instance to get more detailed exception information?

Comment: I am running inside vm, what is remote debugging instance.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx